# Codeigniter/PHP upload PDF file does not overwrite existing file on server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

When I upload a pdf file freshly it uploads, but when I try to upload a new one to replace it never really does it (when working on my online version uploaded to my aws instance, since when I work locally it does work correctly)

In other uploads on the app I also upload .rar or .zip and I can overwrite existing files (both locally and on server)

Useful notes before the code:

- I have tried to chmod the folder where I am working, I have tried to delete the file before I upload the new one (using unlink) and also always had "overwrite" argument as true.

---

My form is created in js like this:

```
(...)
    form = '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="enunciado-form" action="'+base_url + 'UploadsC/uploadEnunciadoProjeto/' +proj+'">' +
    '<input class="form-input-file" type="file" id="file_projeto" name="file_projeto" title="Escolher enunciado" accept=".pdf">' +
    '</form>'

    $(".cd-message").html(form);
(...)
```

My php function to upload the form:

```
public function uploadEnunciadoProjeto($project_id)
    {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');

        if($this->verify_teacher($user_id, $project_id, "projeto")){

            $path = './uploads/enunciados_files/';


            if(!is_dir($path)){
                mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE);
            } else {
                chmod($path, 0777);
                chmod("uploads/enunciados_files/" . $project_id . ".pdf", 0777);
            }

            clearstatcache();

            $upload['upload_path'] = $path;
            $upload['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
            $upload['file_name'] = $project_id;
            $upload['max_size'] = 5048;
            $upload['overwrite'] = true;

            $this->load->library('upload', $upload);

            $this->upload->initialize($upload);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_projeto'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                print_r($error);
            }
            else
            {
               header("Location: ".base_url()."projects/project/".$project_id);
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: ".base_url()."errors/403");
        }
    }
```

Mime for pdf:

```
'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/force-download', 'application/x-download', 'binary/octet-stream', 'text/html', 'application/x-pdf'),
```

### Edit

Added 
`echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms("uploads/enunciados_files/" . $project_id . ".pdf")), -4);`
to my php function before and after the chmod and after the unlink and have the following results:

On server:

- Before the chmod: 0644
- After the chmod: 0777
- After the unlink: 0

Which proves that the file is theoretically being deleted but the only PDF upload working is the first one and it never changes.

I wonder if the problem is related to the setup configurations of aws. I also checked and the only .htaccess that I have in the folder actually gives permission to access the folder.

Comment: initial thought, could be cache?

Comment: To overwrite the file it should with the same filename

Comment: I try to clear cache before the upload using "clearstatcache();", not sure if that's the best approach.

Comment: It is the same filename, $project_id, since I am uploading a different file related to the same project (example: 601) it always names the file to "601.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot about the problem, we ended up concluding that this approach wasn't good for what we were trying to achieve, for that, we changed our approach and started using S3_Buckets solution from AWS.

For any possible viewer that ends up with the same problem, I suggest using a solution like buckets instead of what I was doing (saving the uploads on the server root).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

Answer (score 1):

remove the following line of code:

```php
$upload['overwrite'] = true;

$this->load->library('upload', $upload);

$this->upload->initialize($upload);
```

with the following line:

```
// $upload['overwrite'] = true;

$this->load->library('upload', $upload);
$this->upload->overwrite = TRUE; // code added here
$this->upload->initialize($upload);
```

#### edit-01:

add the following line of code to debug:

```php
$error = $this->upload->display_errors();
```

Comment: In localhost it works just like my version does, but on my aws instance it does not overwrite the first upload

Comment: I added that line (I already had it when the upload fails but added it before as well). As expected there is no error, it echoes a empty string, which means theoretically the upload succeed but it doesn't overwrite the existing pdf file on the server upload folder. I am wondering if this is a permission problem but I am also using fileperms($path) in the path of the file before the chmod, before unlinking and after unlinking and the permissions are being changed and suposedly the file is deleted but in reality it stays there everytime I upload a different one

Comment: put `$this->upload->display_errors()` outside if statement